# GetFileSizeEx fails for file mapping

Tags: c, windows, shared-memory

Im having trouble creating a named shared memory and inspecting its size. The function GetFileSizeEx fails when I call it in a function like this. Any ideas on how to debug this?

```
void test_getsize(const char* lpName, int size){

    HANDLE handle = CreateFileMapping(
                     INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                     NULL,                    // default security
                     PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
                     0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                     size,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                     lpName);                 // name of mapping object

    if (handle== NULL || handle== INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        last_error = get_error_from_errorno();
        *error_return =1;
    }


    LARGE_INTEGER new_size;

    err = GetFileSizeEx(handle, &new_size);

    if (err==0){ printf("err ");} else {printf("pass ");}
    printf("size=%lu\n", (unsigned long)new_size.QuadPart);
}
```

Comment: And what is the result of this code?

Comment: You are not using a file, can't get the size of a non-existing file.

Comment: I'm a bit (a lot ?) late, but why don't you use MapViewOfFile/VirtualQuery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handle you pass to `GetFileSizeEx` must be a handle to a file. You are passing it a handle to a file *mapping*, which is a completely different thing, so it won't work.

Since apparently you want the size of the file mapping (called a *section object*), and I don't think the Win32 API provides this feature, you would need to use the native Windows API called [`NtQuerySection`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Section/NtQuerySection.html). Here's an idea of how it might work (I haven't tried it):

```
typedef enum _SECTION_INFORMATION_CLASS
{
    SectionBasicInformation,
    SectionImageInformation
} SECTION_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION {
  PVOID         Base;
  ULONG         Attributes;
  LARGE_INTEGER Size;
} SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION;

typedef DWORD (WINAPI* NTQUERYSECTION)
    (HANDLE, SECTION_INFORMATION_CLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);
NTQUERYSECTION NtQuerySection =
    (NTQUERYSECTION)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySection");

SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION SectionInfo = { 0 };
NTSTATUS = NtQuerySection(handle, SectionBasicInformation, &SectionInfo,
    sizeof(SectionInfo), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have since found that the HANDLE returned is a Section Object. how do I query the size of a section object?

I've read about 'ZwQuerySection' but it only seems to be on windows NT.

Comment: @sean: You don't call `Zw*` functions from user mode. Use the `NtQuerySection` function as I've outlined in my updated answer.

Comment: Since NtQuerySection is an undocumented API, there's no guarantee it'll be there or work the same way in a future version of Windows.  Why not simply remember the size used to create the section object?

Comment: I can't remember the size because the memory mapped handle was created in another process.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with NtQuerySection. It is returning the Status 0xC0000004 (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH). 
    `The specified information record length does not match the length that is required for the specified information class.`

But I have not seen any headers that show the SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION struct as being any different. does anyone have a working example of NtQuerySection?

Comment: @sean: Are you on a 64-bit machine? If so, you may need to change the first `ULONG` to a `PVOID` as I've done in my example.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This works great. Also, I think the Size retured may be a multiple of the page size, but I will have to look into this.